# get multiselect select tag value as an array in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i used multiselect select tag.

In  create method i used,

```
category= @admin.category.reject! { |c| c.empty? }.to_s
```

to save my select tag (selected)value as array  into database.

But in update method the same thing is not get achieve. 
original format what i am getting is,

```
--- - '' - Adventure Tours - Cruises - Exploration
```

I want to change it as an array like

```
["Adventure Tours","Cruises","Exploration"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'serialize' method provided by ActiveRecord to store values as array into the database.

The type of the column in which you are store these array of values should be text

Ex : (Say if you want to save codes of categories in categories table)

```
# In the migration file
add_column :categories, :codes, :text 

# In the model
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :codes
end
```

It will get saved in the database as

```
---
- abc 
- xyz
- pqr
```

and after fetching it from the database, like

```
Category.find(some_id).codes
```

You will get an array of codes for that given category record.

```
["abc", "xyz", "pqr"]
```

You can refer this documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize (Search for heading : Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns)